# how to center a semi transparent img on a horizontal line, without letting appear the line below the image?

Tags: css

we wish to make an horizontal line (either using `hr` or just some element with a background), on a web page, and, on the center we should have an image. 
something like this:

```
--------------- &&&& ------------
```

That image is, and has to be, transparent on some parts. (the outline should be always visible, and the transparent part should be fill up with another image trough javascript, making it act as a preloader).

We would create a container div with some image repeating over the x, and place the image centered, but if we do that the lines will be visible even if they are below the image due to the existence of transparency on the image.

The centered image can't be a background img I believe, because we should target it with javascript. (I could be wrong dough).

What can you suggest in order to pull this off ?

also, no white space should exist between the image edges and the line.

```
--------&&&-------
```

failed tries: -coded on phone :s

http://jsfiddle.net/j4eH8/1/

how can I make this to adjust to always take the full viewport width?
http://jsfiddle.net/j4eH8/3/

Update:
could this be a proper way of doing it? or are there any downsides?

http://jsfiddle.net/j4eH8/4/

thanks

Comment: You'll get much more substantial answers if you post code, the specific problem you're running into, and your failed attempts at what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm aware of that. i'm on the phone atm. :/

Comment: @jefffabiny: done code on mobile. updated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Is it this: you want to center a semi-transparent img horizontally and vertically over a line which extends to 100% of the width of the parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just make an image in Photoshop that has the line and all the specifications you want. Something like `<hr><img src="SRC"><hr>` wouldn't work because it would break into two lines ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/j4eH8/)).

**EDIT:** According to your updated fiddle, you figured it out. In terms of better ways of doing this, I think that your way would work, although you would want to test it on a mobile device or shrunken browser to test its responsiveness.

When I test its responsiveness on the fiddle, it seems to work in a smaller browser, although it breaks when it gets too small (about 40 px); however, no screen is so small that it would break.

Long story short, use the fiddle you posted. http://jsfiddle.net/j4eH8/4/